# How to keep two operating system on a laptop having two different Disk Drives?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, bios, multi-boot

I have a [Gigabyte p35x](http://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/P35X-v5#sp) laptop it came with 1 SSD, 1HDD, and i can replace the optical drive with another HDD. 
It has Windows 10 installed on the SSD.
So i removed my HDD(having windows 7) from a previous laptop, and replaced the optical drive with that.
Now how can i boot on the second HDD(windows7) ? when i try from the bios to choose the booting device, i have only one option which is the SSD (NVMe)

Any idea how i can set dual boot ? so that i can choose between Windows 10 or 7 when it boots ?

Comment: Its worth remembering many SKUs of windows don't have transferable licences or activation locked to specific hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Windows 7 disk is visible when booting into Windows 10,
then you could add it to the boot menu by using the tool `bootrec.exe`
that is built-in to the Windows recovery environment.

This is the procedure :

1. Hold down either SHIFT key while clicking on Restart, available from any Power icon, and wait for the Advanced Startup Options menu to appear.​
   In case of any difficulty, alternate methods to get to this menu are [described here](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-access-advanced-startup-options-in-windows-10-or-8-2626229).
2. Open Command Prompt from Advanced Startup Options or System Recovery Options menu.
3. At the prompt, type the command `Bootrec.exe /ScanOS`, 
   to determine if the system recognizes windows 7.
4. To add Windows 7 to the boot menu execute:
   `Bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd`,
   which will scan the disks for all compatible installations with Windows and let you choose which to add to the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store.

Answer (score 0):

- Use classic MBR boot mode if you have UEFI BIOS.
- Connect only one drive. Install Operating system on it.
- Disconnect the initial drive, connect second one, install second operating system there.
- Reconnect the initial drive.
- Select which one you want to boot from using the BIOS hot-keys.

Comment: Is it not possible to do that without the need to reinstall ? Because my system is up and running with all my programs tools and settings... And I really want to avoid reinstall again

Comment: You can do it without reinstall by just rebuilding the boot sector of the not working one. Connect it, start the OS by it's installation disk, open a command prompt and fix the MBR.